# React-Final-Form <FormSpy /> get changed field props/metadata

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have a settings form where I use  to auto-save changes. The form has many checkboxes and select inputs with a few text inputs. I want to debounce only the changes in the form from text input fields and not checkbox or select.

How can I get the Field metadata ie: `type` attr inside my FormSpy change handler?

Comment: Cory, did you resolve this issue? I'm trying to do something similar, but couldn't figure out how to do so from the docs...

Comment: Yeah, eric the owner of react-final-form suggested an idea to me on twitter but i can't find the tweet now. It never really solved what this question is asking though

Comment: Thanks for replying! I will try to contact him via Twitter and see if he can help out.

Comment: I believe you'd have to debounce the field itself for textfields. That would delay values being updated which would delay formspy from firing as long as your subscribing to values.